# How to get the objectId from saveAllInBackground on the android sdk of Parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform, objectid

I need to batch save some objects in Parse.com and it works fine, but I can't get the **objects ids** using the traditional way. I'm using **saveAllInBackroung**, passing a **ArrayList** of **ParseObjects**. The data is saved and the callback succeed, but my ParseObjects inside the ArrayList don't get any extra data, including the objectId.

```
                    objectsToUpload = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int titleIndex      = cursor.getColumnIndex(Items.TITULO);
                    int subtitleIndex   = cursor.getColumnIndex(Items.SUBTITULO);
                    int syncedIndex     = cursor.getColumnIndex(Items.SYNCED);
                    int dateIndex       = cursor.getColumnIndex(Items.DATE);
                    int entryIdIndex    = cursor.getColumnIndex(Items.ENTRY_ID);
                    int idIndex         = cursor.getColumnIndex(Items._ID);

                    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                        String title = cursor.getString(titleIndex);
                        String subtitle = cursor.getString(subtitleIndex);
                        String date = cursor.getString(dateIndex);
                        int syncedInt = cursor.getInt(syncedIndex);

                        ParseObject object = new ParseObject(Constants.PARSE_OBJ_NAME);
                        object.put(Items._ID, idIndex);
                        object.put(Items.TITULO, title);
                        object.put(Items.SUBTITULO, subtitle);
                        object.put(Items.SYNCED, true);
                        object.put(Items.DATE, date);

                        objectsToUpload.add(object);

                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }

                    ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(objectsToUpload, new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if ( e == null )
                            {

                                for ( int i =0; i < objectsToUpload.size(); i++ )
                                {

                                    ParseObject obectUploaded = objectsToUpload.get( i );

                                    String objId = objectsToUpload.get( i ).getObjectId().toString();
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    });
```

The string objId return null. And in the debugging the ParseObjects inside the objectsToUpload don't have anything besides the info that I putted earlier.

Comment: Can you edit the ParseObject class saveAllInBackground method?

Comment: If yes, I have an answer.

Comment: I don't think that I can. It's a compiled sdks from Parse. Never tried.
What would you do?

Comment: It works in a different thread so you can not get your modified list from the main thread like that. You can pass the modified list in the done method as input to the main thread.

Comment: So for your understanding I should modify the method from the sdk? Have you done this before? If so, could you help me a bit? I checked and it's a ton o code there. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Where your list is saved (SQL Lite, User defaults, vs.)? You can read your list again in done method. SDK should handle this condition, I think you dont need to modifiy it.

Comment: Well ondermerol, I guess this is what I'm trying to do. Although there is no result in my list inside the **done** method. I tried to debug and checked the variables values (inside the done method) and there is nothing besides what I putted in. If you could be so kind to type some code to explain me better your solution it would be **awesome**! (I'm stuck here)

Comment: You can use listeners to communicate, pass values between your main thread and another thread. You can search google for it and to be a good android developer, you should know how they work.

Comment: I really don't know why you've got the trouble to come here and comment if you can't help. And there is no need to bee rude. For your information the code is running on a separate thread. On a syncAdapter actually. And the Parse sdk theoretically provides the logic to handle the messages between the server, client and threads. So, considering the documentation of Parse and the way any other operation using this sdk works, my code is fine. Go "help" another one please

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a proper solution inside the Parse SDK for Android, although I managed to solve the problem using the **RESTApi** with the Volley Library.
It works just fine and I can recovery the ids of the saved objects.

I recommend **Volley** because it is a really simple way to send and receive JsonObjects with all the background work done for you. It could be a little tricky to get the hang of it, but you could look into this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/).

A litte *snippet* of my solution

```
  final Cursor cursor = fetchUnSynced();
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int titleIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SyncAdapterContract.Items.TITULO);
        int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SyncAdapterContract.Items._ID);

        JSONObject dataToUpload    = new JSONObject(); // The complete data to upload
        JSONArray requestsArray   = new JSONArray();   // Objects list

        //Strings defined at parse.com
        final String url        = "https://api.parse.com/1/batch";
        final String REQUESTS   = "requests";
        final String METHOD     = "method";
        final String PATH       = "path";
        final String BODY       = "body";
        final String pathUrl    = "/1/classes/VolleyTest"; //Change to suit you needs
        final String req_tag    = "parse_batch";

        //Iterate
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            String title = cursor.getString(titleIndex);

            JSONObject requestObj   = new JSONObject(); //Request for each object
            JSONObject bodyObjs     = new JSONObject(); //Data of object

            try {
                //Body
                bodyObjs.put(SyncAdapterContract.Items.TITULO, title);
                //whatever else you have to upload at each object

                //Request
                requestObj.put(METHOD, "POST");
                requestObj.put(PATH, pathUrl);
                requestObj.put(BODY, bodyObjs);

                requestsArray.put( requestObj );

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        try {
            dataToUpload.put(REQUESTS, requestsArray);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayReq = new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, url, dataToUpload,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Response with the ids and status of each object

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //Error
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put( "X-Parse-REST-API-Key", Constants.PARSE_API_KEY );
                headers.put( "X-Parse-Application-Id", Constants.PARSE_APP_ID );
                return headers;
            }
        };

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(MyApp.getsInstance()).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayReq, req_tag );
```

Things to consider:

- The batch operation support only **50 objects per call**
- The correct implementation of volley should consider a **Singleton Class** to deal with the Queues